# Accessing JComponents from keyListener

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener

1. `JPanel(a).JPanel(b).JLabel`
2. `JPanel(a).JTextArea`

I have added a `KeyListener` to `JTextArea`. When it gets invoked, it's supposed to acess the `JLabel` and return `getText()`.

I can get to `JPanel(a)` by `getSource()`/`getParent()`, but i don't know how to then "turn around" and go the other way...

Is that possible and how?

Comment: Why not simply provide some getters ...

Comment: You can use [Container.getComponent(0)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponent(int)) but i agree with @Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

```
JPanel a = (JPanel) ((Component) arg0.getSource()).getParent();
JPanel b = (JPanel) a.getComponent(0);
String textInJLabel = ((JLabel) b.getComponent(0)).getText();
```

For whoever stumbles upon this, watch out to set the indexes right in `getComponent(int index)` method. The ones in this codes work for my case.